# How does RStudio 'lm' know my data is a polynomial equation?

Tags: r, regression, logistic

I'm following along with a "learn R" course, and we ran the following multiple linear regression:

```
regressor = lm(formula = Profit ~ ., data = training_set)
```

Then a bit later, we added some columns to a different data set:

```
dataset$Level2 = dataset$Level^2
dataset$Level3 = dataset$Level^3
dataset$Level4 = dataset$Level^4
```

And ran identical line...

```
regressor = lm(formula = Profit ~ ., data = training_set)
```

And somehow now `lm` knows not to fit a multiple regression linear line?

It's modifying the original data set before it's even passed into `lm`, so unless `lm` is somehow trying to interpret my data to figure out which actual model to use, I don't see how it's knowing to do this...?

Comment: A linear model refers to a model which is linear in the parameters. It doesn't matter that some of your regressors are powers of each other, that is still a linear model. There is no special consideration that `lm` needs to make for this.

Comment: Ok true, I understand that part I probably used the wrong terminology (because "linear" references the `x*` term and not the `x^2`). But in a simple or multiple linear regression its a best fitting "straight line", solved for either by gradient descent or analytically, right? So how does, in this case, it know to use some other method to make a model who's function generates a curved line instead of straight. I can only imagine it is using some strategy to fit the line that isn't used in a simple or multiple linear regression?

Comment: I'm wondering what that extra method is called... and furthermore (the purpose of this question), how R knows to use that function just based on my data, rather than an actual fitted straight line, when I didn't actually tell it to do that.

Comment: The terminology is not a minor detail here: there is mathematically absolutely no difference between a model in which you have these powers or not, you still have a linear model. There is no "extra method".

Comment: @ChrisHaug Hmm... Isn't the `lm` formula "solving" for the slope and y intercept of the regression line using some method? In certain dataset inputs, the line is straight, as if it were solving `y = mx + b` and other times, the outputted line is not straight (including `x^2 + x^3` in the data etc), I'm wondering what mechanism is making this happen? Why are some model lines straight (even with multiple independent variables, like in a "multiple linear regression"), and then a curved line is output for other datasets?

Comment: I know your question isn't about confidence intervals and the duplicate is: nevertheless, your question appears to be fully answered in the duplicate thread.

Comment: Ah I see, it didnt show up until I actually had to refresh. Thanks Ill have a look

Comment: Multiple linear regression is not 'fitting a line'